# Dell Boomi - How do you move an email from Inbox to an Inbox Sub-folder?

Tags: email, integration, move, inbox, boomi

I have a Dell Boomi Integration process that runs, and after it finishes It's supposed to move from the Inbox to a another folder called Voucher Processed. However the process recognizes the Inbox but says that Voucher Processed does not exist.

[image]

**This is what I have set:**

[image]

**Within the Set Properties Shape:**

[image]

**Then the Mail (IMAP) Operation as follows:**

[image]

I attempted to follow the Boomi Training example called

> Mail (IMAP) Basics: Move an email

to set up what I currently have. Like I said at the beginning the Inbox is being acknowledged but it doesn't seem to recognize the Voucher Processed folder.

Is this because it's a sub-folder of the Inbox? If so, how should I be setting that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to change my static value to "Inbox/Voucher Processed" and it worked just fine.

It was treating it as a sub-directory of Inbox.